# Ignore warnings in entire subfolder

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, directory-structure

I have resource files connected with some source in a sub directory, like this:

```
__init__.py
one.py
subdir/
    __init__.py
    two.py
    dir_two_resources_but_causes_lots_of_warnings/
```

How can I ignore warnings generated in `dir_two_resources_but_causes_lots_of_warnings` in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... right click and then the solution was there.

[image]